# Python Lemmatizing input list, return output list

Tags: python, lemmatization

I have a list containing strings that I am lemmatizing. Though I can lemmatize all the strings, I am having a hard time returning the lemmatized strings in the same list format that I inputted to the lemmatizer.

Doing a type of each of the outputs, I get a unicode and str objects. I tried converting the unicode to strings and tried to concatenate the strings to a list but with no luck.

Below is the reproducible code:

```
typea = ['colors', 'caresses', 'ponies', 'presumably', 'owed', 'says']
for i in xrange(0,len(typea)):
    # Lemmatize the words
    lemmatized_words = lmtzr.lemmatize(typea[i])
    print lemmatized_words

    #Output obtained: 
    color
    caress
    pony
    presumably
    owed
    say
    #Desired output
    #['color', 'caress', 'pony', 'presumably', 'owed', 'say']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lmtzr.lemmatize` takes a single string and returns a single string. So `lemmatized_words` will be a single string at a time.

To lemmatize all the words and store them in a list, you want something like this:

```
typea = ['colors', 'caresses', 'ponies', 'presumably', 'owed', 'says']
lemmatized_words = [lmtzr.lemmatize(x) for x in typea]
print lemmatized_words
```