# Iterate and Lemmatize List

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, lemmatization

I'm a newbie and struggling with what I'm sure is a simple task.

I have a list of words taken from `POS tagging`:

```
words = ['drink', 'drinking']
```

And I want to `lemmatize` them and then process them (using `set`?) to ultimately refine my list to:

```
refined_list = ['drink']
```

However, I"m stuck on the next step of lemmatization - my method still returns the following:

```
refinded_list = ['drink', 'drinking']
```

I tried to reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747659/python-lemmatizing-input-list-return-output-list) but can't figure out what to import so 'lmtzr' works or how to get it to work.

Here's my code so far:

```
import nltk
words = ['drink', 'drinking']
WNlemma = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
refined_list = [WNlemma.lemmatize(t) for t in words]
print(refined_list)
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk to understand how lemmatizer might give you gotcha =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `pos` tag parameter from `lemmatize` as VERB. By default it is NOUN.
So it considers everything as NOUN even if you pass the VERB.

```
import nltk
words = ['drink', 'drinking']
WNlemma = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
refined_list = [WNlemma.lemmatize(t, pos='v') for t in words]
print(refined_list)
```

Output:

```
['drink', 'drink']
```